# Union Types expecting other type when passed as props to component?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, react-redux

I'm using Typescript with React.

I am retrieving data from an API that returns two type: `VirtualMachine` or `Disk`. The backend takes responsibility for distinguishing the resource type and returns the type of both depending on the results of the query:

```
requestMoreInfo: (resourceType: string, resourceId: number): AppThunkAction<ResourceActions> => (dispatch, getState) => {
    let fetchResourceInfo = fetch('http://localhost:5004/GetResourceTypeInformation/' + resourceType + '/' + resourceId, {
        method: 'GET'
    })
```

I've declared a union type for my Redux state:

```
export interface ResourceState {
    currentResourceInformation?: VirtualMachineInformation | DiskInformation;
}
```

and I am subsequently converting the response to the type determined by the resource type passed into the function and dispatching an action to update my components state. THIS IS WHERE I THINK I'M GOING WRONG.

```
if (resourceType == "Virtual Machine") {
  var vmResponse = response.json() as VirtualMachineInformation;

  dispatch({
    type: 'RECEIVE_RESOURCE_INFO',
    resourceInfo: vmResponse
  });
}
else if (resourceType == "Disk") {
  var diskResponse = response.json() as DiskInformation;
  dispatch({
    type: 'RECEIVE_RESOURCE_INFO',
    resourceInfo: diskResponse
  });
}
```

TypeScript appears to be happy with this. However, I am then trying to render a child component and passing this update state as a prop:

```
private requestResourceInformation = (resourceType: string, resourceId: number) => {
    this.props.requestMoreInfo(resourceType, resourceId);

    if (resourceType == "Virtual Machine") {
        return <VirtualMachineResource virtualMachine={this.props.currentResourceInformation} />
    }
}
```

This just maps a table with the data.

However, I'm retrieving the error:

```
  Type 'VirtualMachineInformation | DiskInformation | undefined' is not assignable to type 'VirtualMachineInformation | undefined'.
    Type 'DiskInformation' is not assignable to type 'VirtualMachineInformation | undefined'.
      Type 'DiskInformation' is not assignable to type 'VirtualMachineInformation'.
        Property 'azureVmId' is missing in type 'DiskInformation
```

I believe this is because TypeScript still considers the value as the union type and the expected value is present in `VirtualMachine` type but no present in the `Disk` type.

Where am I going wrong with this? Is there an explicit way to declare the specific type of the union after retrieving the data?

Comment: yes, this is possible and you are already doing that in your code by the `as` keyword - it's called type casting or type assertions - https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions

Comment: Have you tried to cast it where you assign it to the VirtualMachineResource , like so  ```if (resourceType == "Virtual Machine") {
  const info = <VirtualMachineInformation>this.props.currentResourceInformation;
        return <VirtualMachineResource virtualMachine={info} />
    }```

Comment: you can also make a use of type guards https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards or overloads http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#overloads

Comment: @Roomy That was my assumption, but according to the Typescript compiler, it is unable to determine the type at time when the child component is being rendered.

Comment: @dashton This would work, but I think with this being `.tsx` its interpreting the `<>` tags as JSX. Maybe this is my problem.

Comment: @Roomy @dashton Turns out I was being a little dumb. Because this is a .tsx file, I have to use `as` to assign it during the component rendering. Rather then the normal way with `<Type>xyz`. Thank you for all your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `virtualMachine` property doesn't accept the `DiskInformation` interface as a value - and that is your problem. TypeScript compiler doesn't know what's the exact type of the value at the compile time so the type is guessed to be one among those three: `VirtualMachineInformation`, `DiskInformation`, `undefined`

As I wrote in the comments section - you can use (at least) three solutions to solve your problem:

1. use type assertions - https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions - you can not use `<Type>value` syntax in *tsx* files
   `return <SomeComponent prop={value as Type}></SomeComponent>`
2. use type guards https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards

   `if ([check if type of the value is the Type]) {
       return [something else]
   }
   [TypeScript knows that the value IS NOT an instance of the Type here]
   return <SomeComponent prop={value}></SomeComponent>`
3. use overloads - http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#overloads

   `class X {
       private y(x: "abc"): "cda";
       private y(x: "cda"): "abc";
       private y(x: string): string {
           [method logic]
       }
   }`

Comment: Adding to this - Turns out I wasn't doing anything wrong, I just wasn't correctly casting the type at the point when I was passing the prop to the component. Type assertions were specifically the answer to my problem. Just using the correct context in the TSX file (`as` rather then `<type>`